# Spring Boot send array of objects to controller with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So, I followed some other questions on how to set spring boot controller to parse incoming data, which is **array of objects**.

I am sending data in next form:

```
var myData = [ {lang_id : 1, title : "blabla", description : "blablabla"}, {lang_id : 2, title : "der text", description : "der text"}, ... ] 

$.ajax({
    url: "/test2",
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:'application/json'   
    ,success : function(res){
        console.log("ok!", res.data);
    }
    ,error : function(a,b,c){
        console.log("err!", a, b, c);
    }
});
```

According to other answers, i have made my response and response wrapper object.

```
public class Response {
    private Integer lang_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    //getter and setters
}

public class RequestWrapper {
    private List<Response> items;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Then, i set my controller as follows:

```
@PostMapping(value="/test2")
public @ResponseBody RequestWrapper postIt(@RequestBody RequestWrapper req) {
    System.out.printf("\n\n%s\n\n", req);
    return req;
}
```

Any every single answer had solution like this, yet this one doesn't work for me. I get following error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.mypackage.controllers.RequestWrapper out of START_ARRAY token;
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.mypackage.controllers.RequestWrapper out
>   of START_ARRAY token

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
public @ResponseBody RequestWrapper postIt(@RequestBody Response[] req)
```

Given your `RequestWrapper` POJO, the correct JSON is of the following form:

```
{
  "items": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: The problem was in second part of your answer, now i can get my data. thanks